# Display Popup when text is clicked in wordpress

Tags: text, popup, wordpress

I have a Html code In wordpress.:

'`<a href="">example</a>`'

When this "example" is clicked, it needs to show a popup window with some texts.
i came across some wordpress popup plugins like uji popup,etc..
they given some short codes. how can i use this shortcodes into my "href".
or any other plugins i can use, or any easy ideas to display popup when this text is clicked in wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can used bootstrap modal popup. as like demo

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. it's what i am looking for..
still one clarification, after i closed th popup, page's background is dark, button also not working for second time.

Comment: it's bootstrap popup. it' some problem in you js script. if it's live give me url i will check it.

Comment: I am doing it in Localhost. Yet i gotit! i removed the

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Now it is working exactly!